# How to use API data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a React app in in which I have to make calls to an API. I created a `dataService.js` where I will create all the functions with the calls to my API.

In the component in which I need to retrieve the data, I simply try to console.log the data but I have a `Promise {<pending>}` instead of the result I need... What can I do to retrieve the data ?

My initial idea is to retrieve all the data I need using this `dataService.js` and setting the state of the component with the data. I guess it is possible but how ?

**dataService.js**:

```
export const dataService = {dataValue};

function dataValue() {
    return axios.get('url/to/api')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.soc) //this works well !
            let soc = response.data.soc
            return soc;
        });
}
```

**myComponent.js**:

```
class myComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        let test = dataService/dataValue(); // I imported the dataService !
        console.log(test);
        return (<div></div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: have you searched for existing questions/answers? this is not a unique question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend using React Hooks, combined w/ Function Components to retrieve data. Something like this:

- On [Function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)
- On [Hooks & Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#hooks-and-function-components)
- On [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html);
- On [useState Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html);
- On [useEffect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html);

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('url/to/api')
        .then(response => {
            setData(response);
        });
  }, []);

return (<div>{data.map(d => <<DO WHATEVER YOU WANT W/ DATA HERE>>)}</div>);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Making an API request is asynchronous.
So u need an async function here

```
const dataValue = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('url/to/api');
    return response.data.soc;
}
```